# How to associate file extension in browser?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, file-extension

We have a program that associates with the '.test' file extension. It works fine in Windows, but it will not work if we upload (the `clickme.test`) to the internet and open it inside the browser (IE/Firefox/Chrome). All the browser does is open and display the file content on the browser instead of opening the program that is associated with the file extension.

Any idea would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**: We follow everything by adding the value into the registry just like the torrent magnet link, but its still not working for us :/

Any chance it is because ours is a stand-alone `.exe` file? We just compile the program and add the registry using the program and restart the PC.

**Edit**: We are able to 'initiate' the program now by copying how the magnet link work. But it seems to get stuck at 'processing the data'. Will play with it later as busy with other stuff now.

Answer (score 0):

That's how the system is supposed to work. You will need to change the setting for that file to only allow it to be downloaded instead of opening, as the browser will opening it.

Depending on your file hosting this may or may not be possible. If you have your own webserver, you should be able to force a download only option.

Comment: hi, yes, we do own the webserver. we upload it to one of the folder and click on the '.test' file. pls advice on howto 'force download'

Comment: That's depending on how your server is setup but there are some examples on here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531292/php-how-to-force-download-of-a-file is one and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36522919/how-to-allow-only-my-php-file-to-download-a-file . Both of these are directed towards php control. So these may not be helpful on your webserver.

Comment: hi, we want it to open our program now download the file. is it possible?

Comment: we try create a html file with this link, but it will open up the download dialog and not running our program - <a href="file link" download target="_blank">Click here to download</a>

Comment: @aboka You will need to download the file before you can run it, this is generally done due to security. You wouldn't want people to run programs from a web browser as it's a security risk.

Comment: we hope to find a 'one click' solution. found a piece of info advicing howto add a magnet link. wonder if could make this work for us?

The solution in Windows 7 is to edit the registry entry for magnet links. Open regedit and change the value of HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\magnet\shell\open\command\ to match the program you want to use to open magnet links, the associated icon is defined in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\magnet\DefaultIcon

Comment: @aboka I wouldn't see that as possible, if it was, it would be exploited on viruses all the time.

Comment: there must a a way just like torrent magnet link. we hv add this to the registry but it still not opening :(

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\runtestfile\shell\open\command]
@="D:\AssociateExtension.exe \"%1\""
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.test]
@="runtestfile"

Answer (score 0):

it is possible with a 'hack' - by copying how magnet link works with a little twist to how our program runs.

by right it should start the program and read the instructions on the .test file and run accordingly; but since we could not read the file if its on a webserver, we will read the info on its 'link', and use the link to run our program to download the file and run it locally.

although not a straight forward way to do it, but user would not know the difference. all they see is 'one click' operation either offline or online.

we rest the case here. and would update this if we find a better solutions to this.

cheers!